# An open set is compact or not if not how??

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $S =(– 10, 10)$. The family $F = 
\{]– n, n[ : n \in \mathbf N\}$ is an open cover of $\mathbf R$. The family $F_∗ = \{]– n, n[ : 1 \leq n \leq 12\}$ is a finite sub-family of $F$ that covers $S$. Is $S$ compact or not?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What does $F$ have to do with anything? Also, MathJax is encouraged for typesetting math

Comment: You have to find a finite subcover for *any* given open cover, not for a specific one. The cover consisting of the intervals $(-10, 10 -1/n)$ for all $n$ does not have a finite subcover.

Comment: Every topological space $X$, compact or not, has a finite open cover, namely the family $\{X\}$. So yeah, it is not suprising that $F_*$ is a finite subfamily that covers $S = (-10,10) = \, ]\!-10,10[$, and in fact $\bigl\{\,]\!-10,10[\,\bigr\}$ is a still smaller finite subfamily that covers $S$. Quantifiers matter, as the comment of @Thomas indicates.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of compactness is not that *one* open cover of your set has a finite subcover, but that *every* open cover of your set has a finite subcover.

**Example**.  Let $I = \{x : a < x < b\}$ be an open interval, where $a < b$.  For $\varepsilon > 0$, let
$U_\varepsilon = (a+\varepsilon, b-\varepsilon)$. When $\varepsilon < (b-a)/2$ we have $a+\varepsilon < b-\varepsilon$, so $U_\varepsilon$ is an open interval and
$$
I = \bigcup_{0 < \varepsilon < (b-a)/2} U_\varepsilon.
$$
Thus these $U_\varepsilon$'s together are an open cover or $I$.  But no finite number of them have a union containing $I$, so they have no finite subcover. Thus $I$ is not compact.

**Example**.  Let $J = \{x : a \leq x \leq b\}$, where $a < b$.
This set *is* compact, and it's the simplest and most important example of a compact set. To prove the compactness of $J$, you can't just pick one example of an open cover of $J$ and find a finite subcover. (Do you see that the $U_\varepsilon$'s above are not an open cover of $J$, and if you enlarge that collection to get an open cover, say by throwing in some tiny intervals like $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ and $(b-\delta,b+\delta)$, do you see that you will be able to find a finite subcover?) A genuinely new idea to needed to prove that *every* open cover of $J$ has a finite subcover.